# How to make visioforge run

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sdk, screen-capture

I am having trouble getting a screen capture program to work that I am trying to replicate from a YouTube video.  the picture is the error I am getting and my code is supplied. I do not believe my error is in my code I think there is a file I am supposed to run or add somewhere but I can not figure out what I need to do.

[IMMAGE OF ERROR WHEN HITTING BUTTON 1 (START BUTTON)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFsYt.png)

[IMMAGE OF THE ERROR WHEN THE PROGRAM IS PUBLISHED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVYAQ.png)

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using VisioForge.Types.OutputFormat;


namespace SCREEN_RECORDER_V2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            videoCapture1.Screen_Capture_Source = new
                            VisioForge.Types.Sources.ScreenCaptureSourceSettings()
            { FullScreen = true };

            videoCapture1.Audio_PlayAudio = videoCapture1.Audio_RecordAudio = false;

            videoCapture1.Output_Format = new VFAVIOutput();

            videoCapture1.Output_Filename = Environment.GetFolderPath
                (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos) + "\\output.avi";

            videoCapture1.Mode = VisioForge.Types.VFVideoCaptureMode.ScreenCapture;

            videoCapture1.Start();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            videoCapture1.Stop();

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on my test, I reproduced your problem in the picture. After some attempts, I can capture the screen successfully.

First, you could download `x64` or `x86` exe both by clicking Base package->x64 or x86 in the picture you provided.

Second, please run as administrator to the run the exe.

**Third**, please install the nuget-package `SDK redist base package` [x86](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VisioForge.DotNet.Core.Redist.Base.x86/) or [x64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VisioForge.DotNet.Core.Redist.Base.x64/) and `Video Capture SDK redist package` [x86](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VisioForge.DotNet.Core.Redist.VideoCapture.x86/) or [x64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/VisioForge.DotNet.Core.Redist.VideoCapture.x64/).

Finally, after publish the program or directly click the button1 to start the record.

Comment: I have added another picture of the error when the program is published.  i am still unable to get the program to function.

Comment: @BigRed, I have updated my answer-> Third. Based on my test, there is no error in current project or published project after I add the above nuget-packages.

Comment: Is there a certain place I can add these files to my program? When I run them and rebuild and publish the project I am getting the same error. Even when I run the files as administrator.

Comment: @BigRed, there is no specific place to add there files. I recommend that you create a new winform app to make the screen-capture app. In order to make your app run, I suggest that you installed x64 and x86 sdk and nuget-package both.